# Show only lines which contain numbers

Tags: sed, grep, find

I have a file with the following lines:

```
irakli1
iraklikairakli
ikarkalsi1
iarksldisrii3
irakli
```

and I want to show only the lines which contain numbers.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
sed -n '/a/'p irakli.txt
```

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to print the lines that contains a number?

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2):

A simple one with `grep`

```
grep '[0-9]' irakli.txt
```

with the file snippet you supplied, you would end up with

```
irakli1
ikarkalsi1
iarksldisrii3
```

Comment: can you please time how to Fill in results? for example result = name i want to write eman

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are asking. Could you rephrase the question?

Comment: @Irakli, do you mean `result=$(grep '[0-9] irakli.txt)`